# Grails 3.1.8: Scaffolded edit.gsp doesn't indent hasMany set

Tags: grails, gsp, scaffolding

This is the brand new project that just contains Book and Author domain classes and scaffolded controllers and views.  The layout seems broken for books, but perhaps this is just a styling change from previous versions.  Can someone help me figure out if this is a bug in Grails, something I'm doing wrong, or the way it's supposed to be?

[image]

Here is ALL the code...

**Author.groovy**

```
package library

class Author {

    String name
    static hasMany = [books:Book]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**AuthorController.groovy**

```
package library

class AuthorController {

    static scaffold = Author
}
```

**Book.groovy**

```
package library

class Book {

    String title
    Author author

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**BookController.groovy**

```
package library

class BookController {

    static scaffold = Book
}
```

Comment: If you would like to contribute any improvements, we welcome pull requests to the repository at https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look into a creating a permanent fix for this and send a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

It's not broken, it just have poor styling. But for prototyping it's enough. If you want to customize the style - you can edit `main.css`. To change scaffolded views layout - run `grails install-templates` and change whatever you want in `src/main/templates/scaffolding`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a quick hack that gets it done.  I don't like it much; but, as @Taras Kohut said, for prototyping it's enough for now.

I'll take a look at the scaffolding plugin to see if I can put together a cleaner fix and create a pull request.

Add this GSP.

**./grails-app/views/_fields/oneToMany/_widget.gsp**

```
<div class="property-value">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-top: -25px;"> <!-- a negative margin... shame on me! -->
        <g:each in="${value?.sort()}" var="val">
            <li><g:link controller="${val.class}" action="show" id="${val.id}">${val}</g:link></li>
        </g:each>
    </ul>
</div>
```